# Using replaceAll() to delete after parenthesis

Tags: java

I am attempting to use replaceAll to delete parenthesis and commas in a numeric line of code as shown below:

```
00020001 OB #2 [00\01] File Meta Information Version
00020002 UI #26 [1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4] Media Storage SOP Class UID
00020003 UI #62 [1.3.46.670589.11.0.0.11.4.2.0.8743.5.5396.2006120114483570701] Media Storage SOP
00020010 UI #20 [1.2.840.10008.1.2.1] Transfer Syntax UID
```

Using this line of code:

`String replaced = dcmObj.toString().replaceAll("[(),*]", "");`

I want to take it one step further and delete everything past the numeric code so for example:

`00020010 UI #20 [1.2.840.10008.1.2.1] Transfer Syntax UID`

Will be turned to just:

`00020010`

Can someone show me how I would do that with the line of code I am using?

Comment: Are you going to apply this regex to string containing your entire text, or just one line?

Comment: @Pshemo I need it to happen for the entire text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try storing number placed ad start of line in group and replace entire line with match from this group.

```
yourTest = yourText.replaceAll("(?m)^(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

`(?m)` represents MULTILINE flag which lets `^` match start of line, not only start of entire string.

DEMO:

```
String s = 
        "00020001 OB #2 [00\\01] File Meta Information Version\r\n" + 
        "00020002 UI #26 [1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4] Media Storage SOP Class UID\r\n" + 
        "00020003 UI #62 [1.3.46.670589.11.0.0.11.4.2.0.8743.5.5396.2006120114483570701] Media Storage SOP\r\n" + 
        "00020010 UI #20 [1.2.840.10008.1.2.1] Transfer Syntax UID";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?m)^(\\d+).*", "$1"));
```

Output:

```
00020001
00020002
00020003
00020010
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work on my side for some reason..It doesn't replace any strings when I add that line of code in....

Comment: `System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?m)^(\\d+).*", "$1"));` doesn't store replaced string in `s` but prints result of `replaceAll` which creates new string. You can try with `s = s.replaceAll(...)`.

Comment: If this doesn't help post code example which sows how you are using this answer.

Comment: I actually went an alternate route that utilized the library I am working with. Thanks for helping, but I am all set :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply match the rest of your string after the digits.

```
replaceAll(" UI.*","")
```

However, I would recommend matching the numerical id instead, it is cleaner and more robust in case your lines format would change

```
id = dcmObj.toString().matches("\d+");
```

Comment: Their not all gonna be like that, I need a generalized regex that would basically kill everything after the numeric value

Comment: use matches instead of replaceAll to extract the id, as in the answer.